# Telegram bot get responses

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I make my bot receives responses without using `force_reply`? something like `botFather` does?

[image: one]

Let say I've sent message to user like this:

```
bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'What is your name?', { parse_mode: 'HTML' });
```

Now how do I get user response?

Answer (score 0):

Without the help of `force_reply`, you'll need to write some custom logic. I've implemented this in my custom bots like so:

1. Send question to user `bot.sendMessage()` and remember the ID
2. Wait for a message `bot.on('message')`
3. Check if we're waiting for on a reply from this user
4. Reply accordingly

```js
// Create bot
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const bot = new TelegramBot('XXXXXXXX:AAEibBwftjTEKuYd9d2X0ACeyyzTk4DLe60', {
    polling: true
});

// List of id's we're waiting for
const wait = [];

// Hardcoded chat id
const chatId = 1234567;

// Ask and add to wait list
bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'What is your name?', { parse_mode: 'HTML' });
wait.push(chatId);

// On message
bot.on('message', (msg) => {

    // Check we're waiting on this user
    if (wait.includes(msg.chat.id)) {

        // Send reply
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Your name: ' + msg.text );

        // Remove from wait list
        wait.splice(wait.indexOf(msg.chat.id), 1);
    } else {

        // Normal message; notify user
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hi! I\'m not expecting a reply from you! How can I help?');
    }
});
```

[image: Example]

---

**Note**: This is just an example! The code can be extended to include multiple checks, and possibly states to see what message the user is replying on.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, your code doesn't work as expected first the issue is your `wait.push(chatId);` is before bot start and wont get any chat id, and if I put it inside `if (text === '/start') {` then it directly prints `Your name: /start`

Comment: PS: by your default code because it doesn't get chat id when user starts the bot it directly shows this error in console `Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: chat_id is empty`